# Set Windows Azure Redis connection string on the portal

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, redis, stackexchange.redis

On redis helper method where I have maintained 2 Redis connection strings.One is for the `local` and the other is for the `Azure redis server`.Each and every time when I need to publish, I have to change it manually.My app is ASP.net MVC (SPA) app.

Q : So is there any place to set published `Redis connection string` on the Azure portal or when I do the publish ?

```
 public class RedisConnectorHelper
    {
     private static readonly Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer> LazyConnection =
            new Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer>(() => ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("localhost,ConnectTimeout=10000"));//local host

     //private static readonly Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer> LazyConnection =
     //   new Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer>(() => ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("Myredis.redis.cache.windows.net:6380,password=mypassword,ssl=True,abortConnect=False"));//production
}
```

**Update :**

I have set that on the `web.config.release` file as shown below.

```
<connectionStrings>

    <add name="Abp.Redis.Cache" connectionString="Myredis.redis.cache.windows.net:6380,password=mypassword=,ssl=True,abortConnect=False" />

  </connectionStrings>
```

But it seems not picked it up. Could you tell me why ?

[image]

Comment: How is your application deployed - Web Apps, Cloud Services or in a VM?

Comment: @GauravMantri `Web Apps`

Comment: You could look at web.config transformation and put appropriate connection string in web.config.release file. So when the application is built in "Release" mode, it picks up correct connection string from there.

Comment: @GauravMantri Will it pick the `Redis connection string` also other than the `db connection string` ?

Comment: Yes it should pick it up.

Comment: @GauravMantri But I don't need to set the `db connection string` on the `web.config.release` file hence I can set it permanently on the Azure portal.Can I have same kind of method for the `Redis cache` also ?

Comment: I don't think so. If I am not mistaken, the connection string for Redis goes into it's own section in web.config.

Comment: @GauravMantri Please see the `Update` section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the trick.Cheers :)

```
#if DEBUG
   private static readonly Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer> LazyConnection =
            new Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer>(() => ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("localhost,ConnectTimeout=10000"));//local host
#else
   private static readonly Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer> LazyConnection =
      new Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer>(() => ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("Myredis.redis.cache.windows.net:6380,password=mypassword,ssl=True,abortConnect=False"));//production
#endif
```